# Stretched camera preview on SurfaceView on Android Studio

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

This is the result I get when I make the SurfaceView smaller. How do I fix this so that it shows correct aspect ratio? I don't want to use the whole image I get from the camera, only a part of it.

Think of it like the Facebook messenger app, when you want to take an instant photo from the app, a small camera window appears. I want the same result. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public static final String TAG = "AKSQS";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        //Take care of rotation and resizing here.

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Camera.Size sizesl : sizes) {
            //This is just to see the supported preview sizes.
            Log.d(TAG, "Width: " + String.valueOf(sizesl.width));
            Log.d(TAG, "Height: " + String.valueOf(sizesl.height));
            Log.d(TAG, "--------");
        }
//        parameters.setPreviewSize(1080,288);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tried to stop a non-existing preview. Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camra preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEx2C.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been bothering me for a month. I finally figured out the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22758359/5273230

Here's the final result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA7CP.jpg

Comment: You can also do it with a FrameLayout; see e.g. Grafika's [AspectFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) and the way it's used in the PlayMovieSurfaceActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

Already found a solution.

First of all we know that every device have different preview size and picture size.

Related from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551241/how-to-calculate-android-screen-aspect-ratio-mathematically) we know how to get correct aspect ratio. See my code

```
    private void searchRatio(Camera.Size size, float ratio) {
        float count1;
//        float ratio = (float) 1.7777778; // 9:16
//        float ratio = (float) 1.0; // 1:1
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            count1 = (float) size.width / (float) size.height;
        } else {
            count1 = (float) size.height / (float) size.width;
        }
        if (count1 == ratio) {
            width.add(size.width);
            height.add(size.height);
        }
    }
```

Here how I use that function

```
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        // set preview size
        for (Camera.Size size : previewSizes) {
            if (ratioPreview != null) {
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                set.clone(binding.getRoot());
                set.setDimensionRatio(binding.surfaceView.getId(), ratioPreview);
                set.applyTo(binding.getRoot());

                if (ratioPreview.equals("9:16")) {
                    searchRatio(size, (float) 1.7777778);
                } else if (ratioPreview.equals("1:1")) {
                    searchRatio(size, (float) 1.0);
                }
            } else {
                searchRatio(size, (float) 1.7777778);
            }
        }
        if (width.size() != 0) {
            param.setPreviewSize(width.get(0), height.get(0));
        }
```

In this case your preview will still stretched. You must set you SurfaceView dimension. This is only simple example, for me I just need 9:16 so I set dimension from xml

```
<SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

After that, my preview is not stretched again.